# Writing to a file prints integers to my IDLE shell

Tags: python-3.4, python-idle

Writing to a file prints integers to my IDLE shell. They seem to range from 15-40 and there's one for every line printed to my file.

This only occurs if I write the statement directly in IDLE, outside of a function. This causes the integers to print:

```
>> file = open('filename', 'w')
>> for element in list:
       file.write('{}\n'.format(element))
```

while this doesn't:

```
>> def print_to_file():
       file = open('filename', 'w')
       for element in list:
           file.write('{}\n'.format(element))
       file.close()
>> print_to_file()
```

I'm using IDLE 3.4.0 on Windows 7. I haven't had the opportunity to test it on another machine or another version of IDLE.

Comment: This is Python's behavior, not Idle's.  Start Python at a console command line (Command Prompt or Power Shell on Windows) with `> python` and you see the same thing. (Or enter `python -i file.py` to enter interactive mode after executing file.py.)  Read-Eval-Print Loops (REPLs) were invented about 30 years before Python.  The point is to print the value of an expression without requireing the user to explicitly enter `print` over and over.  `None` prints nothing. The difference with Python is that it has statements to be executed (which print nothing) as well as expressions to be evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a statement in the interactive interpreter and that statement is an expression that returns a value, the result will be displayed. `write()` returns how many bytes were written.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a `> /dev/null` equivalent for IDLE?

Comment: Not that I know of, but `def null(x): pass` should to the trick: `null(file.write('{}\n'.format(element)))`.

Comment: `_ = file.write(...)` turns the expression into an assignment statement, which has no value to print.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Much more elegant!