# How to make Python file-writing faster with IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

Writing from `file_A` to `file_B` using IDLE always makes IDLE print out the lines as they are being written. If the file is very large, then the process would take hours to finish.

How can I make IDLE **not** print anything while the process of writing to a new file is ongoing, in order to speed things up?

A simple code to demonstrate that IDLE prints the lines as they are being written:

```
file = open('file.csv','r')
copy = open('copy.csv','w')
for i in file:
    i = i.split()
    copy.write(str(i))
```

Comment: I would **not** expect this to generally be the case; are you sure? Could you show a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that displays this behaviour?

Comment: IDLE doesn't print anything as lines are being written, so your problem is already solved.

Comment: @kindall I am an honest person and so I really don't know how to answer to a stupid reply. IDLE does print the lines as they are being written to another file.

Comment: @Dorky please don't descend so rapidly to accusations of stupidity; by default, IDLE **does not** `print` anything on a write operation. Again, please provide an example allowing others to recreate the issue - including details of platform, version, settings, etc. would also be useful.

Comment: @John La Rooy No print statement whatsoever. But IDLE still print the lines out as they are being written.

Comment: Extraordinary claims demand extraordinary proof, is all I can say.

Comment: I want to post the image to show proof but I need 10 reputation to post any image. If you have never use IDLE for file-writing, I don't blame you. But don't make false comments that IDLE does not print while writing the file. Anyone that have experience using IDLE would relate to my experience.

Comment: @Dorky I have literally used IDLE to write to a file, without seeing the behaviour you describe. If you provide links to e.g. imgur uploads I can add them to your question.

Comment: Don't use variables that are the same as built-in Python names like `file` and `copy` - that might be your problem right there.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't want to take unnecessary trouble to prove my honesty in this. Just give me the benefit of the doubt and for once believe that IDLE really does print out the lines as they are being written.

Comment: @Mark Ransom No, the names like file and copy do not matter. I can use any legal name whatsoever and the result is still the same ---> IDLE printing the lines as they are being written. I believe only IDLE users will be familiar with this problem.

Comment: @Dorky I am using IDLE, I have used your test code, **I cannot replicate your problem**: http://imgur.com/ugl2vMU. Note also that you should use the `with` context manager (see the earlier example in my screenshot) to handle files more neatly.

Comment: I use IDLE all the time and I can assure you that I've never seen it behave the way you describe. Neither has anybody else reading this question, or you'd have an answer by now.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I am the only one experiencing a Twilight Zone kind of experience with IDLE.

Comment: Idle executes code in a separate python user process.  Its Shell can only print what python sends back to it.  There may be an error in your copy of python, and you should re-install.  You might have triggered an obscure bug in 3.x's file.write method.  If you have a reproducible example, you should execute it directly in Python, without going through Idle. A better place to dicsuss this would python-list, https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list, also accessible as gmane.comp.python.general at news.gmane.org.

Comment: My comment on this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29114077/writing-to-a-file-prints-integers-to-my-idle-shell adds some background information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Python3 where [`write`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) returns the number of characters written to the file and IDLE's python shell prints this return value when you call it. In Python2 [`write`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) returns `None` that is not printed by IDLE's shell.

The workaround is to assign the return value of write to a temporary dummy variable

```
dummy = f.write("my text")
```

For your example the following code should work

```
file = open('file.csv','r')
copy = open('copy.csv','w')
for i in file:
    i = i.split()
    dummy = copy.write(str(i))
```

---

I added two screenshots for all of you to see the difference between the writes in Python 2 and Python 3 on my system.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It should not print the return value when called from within a loop though.

Comment: @halex Yes, I am using Python 3.4. Yeah, those are probably bytes, but for larger works IDLE will print the entire lines exactly and this really takes up tremendous amount of time.

Comment: @Dorky so you get different behaviour for different sizes of file? Are you using Python 3.x? Again, including as much information as you can in the question will help figure out what's going on.

Comment: @halex Frankly I have no idea how to write a complete code of using that dummy variable, but I am going to experiment on this. I hope you can teach me how to incorporate that dummy code into the loop (or elsewhere) to make it work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you used Python 3.x you would know. At least someone else knew.

Comment: @Dorky I use both, which is why I **specifically asked** which version you were using; *you* didn't add it when editing the question. 3.x will echo the *byte count*, but that is **still** not the behaviour you claim (i.e. echoing the lines)! You are remarkably hostile to people trying to provide you with help for free.

Comment: Sorry, it *does* print out the value even within a loop - I stand corrected.

Comment: Regarding the screenshot, yeah that's the trouble that I am facing. With a file size of 100MB ++ (over 3 million lines), it would take days if not years to finish writing the whole thing. Why is Python 3 doing this? I don't want to regress to Python 2.7 just to get such a simple work done.

Comment: @Dorky and why are you doing it in the interpreter shell? If you just write and run a script, instead, this behaviour doesn't apply. Or assign the value returned by `write`, as suggested; there's no need to switch versions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have no idea what it means by assigning value returned by write. You mean I should use the Windows command prompt to run the script? Or just "Run" with IDLE? I will experiment with that.

Comment: @Dorky With *assigning value returned by write* he means not simply calling `f.write("your text")` but assigning the call to a variable `temp=f.write("your text")`

Comment: @Dorky i.e. `something = write(...)`. If you already are running a script, in IDLE or the command line, you shouldn't be seeing this at all; there's a difference between running code in the shell and running a script. Again, **please give as much detail as you can about what you're doing**; I'd rather edit some out than keep asking!

Comment: Printing the result of calling a function in a loop is something that's apparently changed between Python 2 & 3 _within the Python shell itself_, not IDLE, per se. Personally, I'd call it a bug since there's no way to disable it that I can find. That said, I find it a little odd that someone would be writing files over 100MB long interactively from the shell.

Comment: @martineau that's not the behaviour that's changed (IDLE prints the results of a function called in a loop in both 2.7.9 and 3.4.3 for me) - it's just the fact that `write` now returns something other than `None`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: My point about IDLE vs the shell is I think it's the shell that changed and IDLE is just displaying whatever it (the shell) produces). As for `write`, that would explain what's going on (vs it displaying the data being written to the file, as many thought the OP was claiming).

Comment: @Dorky you may have fixed your problem, but please note that if your original complaint is accurate (i.e. that *the lines themselves* were being shown, rather than the number of bytes) this is **undocumented behaviour in Python** and should be [reported as a bug](http://bugs.python.org/). Please edit the question to clarify accordingly.